# Correct place to run script in vuex flow?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an action, `setProducts`, which I'm passing a payload which returned from a `productSearch()` method.

In my Vue component this looks as follows:

```
let products = productSearch();
this.$store.dispatch('setProducts', products);
```

However, I'm wondering if the correct way to do this would be to refactor my `setProducts` action to `searchProducts` then in my mutator call the `productSearch()` method.

So from my component I run:

```
this.$store.dispatch('searchProducts');
```

Then for my mutator method I'd have something like this:

```
searchProducts(state) {
    state.products = productSearch();
},
```

Is there a more "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better like this:

**Component:**

```
this.$store.dispatch('searchProducts')
```

**Action:**

```
searchProducts(state) {
    commit('updateProducts', productSearch())'
}
```

**Mutator:**

```
updateProducts(state, products) {
    state.products = products
}
```

Actions shouldn't directly affect state's values.
You always need to use commit and mutators to update your store variables, and your mutators should never call functions, they work like setters (receive a variable as paramater and apply it to the state variable).

Comment: thanks, I think you're right, this approach makes more sense than what I had.